# ClamAV doesn't Uninstall completely | Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, uninstall, clamav

A month ago, not sure how but maybe ClamAV got installed during the software update 'apt-get update' & apt-get upgrade'

I complete tried to remove the clamAV using remove or purge, then followed below command to completely remove the package from webpage: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1114606:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove clamav clamav-base clamav-daemon clamav-freshclam libclamav2`

now I do not find anything on clamav in my system

```
ikhan@ik0:~$ apt list --installed | grep clam
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

ikhan@ik0:~$ apt list --installed | grep fresh
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
     
ikhan@ik0:~$ dpkg --list | grep clam
ikhan@ik0:~$ 
ikhan@ik0:~$ dpkg --list | grep fresh
ikhan@ik0:~$
```

But I keep getting this pop-up about the ClamAV daemon is not installed.

[image]

Could someone help to completely remove it !!

Comment: Try `sudo apt update && sudo apt -f install`. Post the output if it didn't work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.. pls find this link: https://pastebin.pl/view/ec23c478

Comment: @Someone, hey.. did you have the chance to look into the requested output ?

Comment: Yes, I saw the outputs now. Try running `dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep clamav | grep -v lib | xargs sudo apt purge --autoremove` Also, try `sudo systemctl disable clamav-freshclam &&
sudo systemctl disable clamav-daemon`

Comment: when I try to run the purge command, it locates the package but aborts in the end automatically.
ikhan@ikhan-T490:~$ sudo dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep clamav | grep -v lib | xargs sudo apt purge --autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-96*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
After this operation, 71.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.

Comment: @Someone, do you suggest I remove all those packages manually ?; https://pastebin.pl/view/83f685c1

Comment: Noooooooo! Those packages are necessary. Please give the output of `dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep clamav` also did you try the other command? Oh wait, the packages are probably getting removed because of auto remove. It means that there are no instances of ClamAV on your machine.

Comment: When I check with the above dpkg command it doesn't list anything. Thus, it tells me that the ClamAV instance is not installed. But idk why I keep getting this notification 'ClamAV daemon is not installed, please install it.'

Comment: its still unresolved, how do I get this case moving ?